# Failed to traverse DOM while rendered inside iframe with section tags

Tags: javascript, dom

I facing a situation which i can't traverse the dom inside iframe. My code is as follows. When i am trying to accessing `childNodes` of `body` tag, console will show there are no `childNodes` inside the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="container"
        src="./resources/c07.xhtml"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

c07.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The section element</h1>

<section>
  <h2>History</h2>
  <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF)</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Symbol</h2>
  <p>The Panda has become the symbol of WWF.</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

//index.js

```
const parentNode = document.querySelector("#container");
const iframeBody =  iframeRef(parentNode);
console.log(element.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('section')); //prints HTMLCollection[] and length is 0

function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
    return frameRef.contentWindow
        ? frameRef.contentWindow.document
        : frameRef.contentDocument
}
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Try to access iframe dom elements in setTimeout function with delay of 1 second.

Comment: tried. But didnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this its working for me. Access iframe dom elements inside `setTimeout` function.

```
const parentNode = document.querySelector("#container");
setTimeout(() => {
  const iframWindow = parentNode.contentDocument;
  console.log(iframWindow.getElementsByTagName("section")); //prints HTMLCollection[] and length is 0
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Created sandbox and check console its printing dom elements
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bash-no9kfs?file=/src/index.js